# QT : INI file read empty Groups

Tags: c++, qt

how can i read group names that are empty in Qt? I load an INI File and want to check that the Group is empty or not. The result must be shown via qDebug();

**Example :**

*INI file:*

[Group1]

[Group2]

bla

bla

```qt5
settings.beginGroup("Group1");  
const QStringList g1 = settings.childKeys(); 
QString vers; 

QFileInfo fileInfo(projectFile);

foreach (const QString &childKey, g1)
{
  QString var = settings.value(childKey).toString();

  if (childKey.contains("bla"))

  {
     vers = var;

    if (OK == vers) 
     {
       qDebug()<<"YES"; 
     } 

    else 
    { 
      qDebug()<<"NO";

    } 
  }
  if (childKey.contains("")) // THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM 
  { 
    qDebug()<<"Nothing in the Group1";
  }
}
settings.endGroup();
```

Comment: What about g1.isEmpty() ?

Comment: I have tried this but that was not the result which i expect. I also use isNull(); 
compare(" "); compare("\0"); compare("\n"). Nothing worked. :(

Comment: Did g1.isEmpty() evaluate to true when the group "Group1" contains no settings? You should do the check before the foreach statement. If so, which result do you expect instead?

Comment: OMG thank you Miki really. I have been sitting on it for an hour ago. :D:D:D:D. Thanks this solves my problem.

Comment: Also, settings.value(childKey) should return and invalid QVariant if the setting does not exists. You can check doing something like: QVariant v = settings.value(childKey); if(!v.isValid()) { // setting not in group}

Comment: Good! Posting as an asnwer then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `g1.isEmpty()` before the `foreach` statement. It should evaluate to true for empty groups.